# Windows 8 taskbar on several monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have windows 8 installed on system with several monitors. On all monitors I have task bar on the bottom. That is fine. But all icons are the same on all task bars. And if I click icon on the one of task bars it might be possible that I activate window on another monitor. Is it possible  to setup somehow that I could have only icons that are active for current monitor for current task bar?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on Taskbar then click `Properties`.

At the bottom under the `Multiple Displays` heading choose the options as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Note: You can't pin items to anything except the main displays Taskbar.